# Identify functional dependencies

Tags: functional-dependencies

Relation:

```
Mobile (Phone number, phone model, owner name, firm name)
```

Firm name is a firm where owner of the mobile phone works.
Functional dependencies are:

```
Phone number -> phone model
Phone number -> owner name
```

Is it right or I am missing something?

Answer (score 2):

I would agree with `Phone number -> owner name` (unless you also want to model phone numbers with no owner at all as a NULL value). I am less sure that `Phone number -> phone model` should hold: usually numbers are associated with SIM cards rather than with devices. You might also add `owner name -> firm name` if every person can work for one and only one employer. Alternatively, if the mobiles phones are provided by the firms, it might be reasonable to assume that every firm provides each employee with exactly one phone number (`firm name, owner name -> Phone number`).

In other words, different functional dependencies are possible, depending on what exactly do you want to model.